# SSRS - Using multiple data sources

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Using 2 DataSources and 2 DataSets in SSRS I am trying to do the following...

List the tasks, with a Boolean variable = true on the project list.

Projects & Tasks are 2 separate DataSources.

Projects are made up of tasks, therefore the tasks DataSource has a Related_Project field.

I would like to show all the tasks that are associated to the projects with that variable - true.

Any help on this? Tried Lookups but to no success.

Comment: I should think lookup would work in this scenario. What do you mean that you had "no success"...no data populating or...? What expression did you use?

Comment: In DataSource1 I have a title_A, which ties to related_title in DataSource2.
In DataSource1 I also have the Boolean variable called red_flag.
I want to show DataSource2 results when the red_flag variable in DataSource1 is true.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your table is limited to use one dataset.

You can achieve your goal using the LOOKUPSET function. It works similar to LOOKUP but returns an array of ALL matches. You can then output this to a cell. Format the textbox as HTML (in the properties tab) and you can output the data with 
 to make a list.

You won't be able to take advantage of groups, sorting and having each value in a cell. If possible, I would recommend writing a query to join your datasets so you can achieve the desired result.